# Comparing 2 rows in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is a history of parts replaced in vehicles.  So over time a vehicle may have the same part swapped several times. I am looking to pull out ONLY the most recent part swaps and the data surrounding only the most recent swaps.  Here's a sample of my table:

| Part | Install_Date | NewSerial Number | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-2-17 | 123456 | Bus1 |
| A | 2022-12-3 | 789101 | Bus1 |
| A | 2021-11-4 | X2349 | Bus1 |
| A | 2022-10-6 | XTY76 | Bus2 |
| A | 2020-9-6 | X56678 | Bus2 |
| B | 2022-6-7 | 123456 | Bus1 |
| B | 2020-5-31 | 56gh6 | Bus1 |

The table goes on as it's much bigger but on my sort I want to have an output that looks like this, with only
the most recent part swaps:

| Part | Install_Date | NewSerial Number | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-2-17 | 123456 | Bus1 |
| A | 2022-10-6 | XTY76 | Bus2 |
| B | 2022-6-7 | 123456 | Bus1 |

I am using MariaDB in a phpMyAdmin shell. I have tried numerous ways. I also do not think MariaDB supports the LAG or LEAD function which is one of the ways I tried it.  Any ideas?

Tried LAG and LEAD, tried various options using JOIN, WHERE clauses, just can't seem to get syntax right?

Answer (score 0):

An "old-fashioned" query without window functions would always be possible:

```
select A.*
from
    Table A
    inner join
    (
        select 
            Vehicle, 
            Part, 
            Max(Install_Date) as MaxOfInstallDate
        from
            Table
        group by 
            Vehicle, 
            Part
    ) B
    on A.Vehicle = B.Vehicle,
    and A.Part = B.Part
    and A.Install_Date = B.MaxOfInstallDate;
```